# System.out.println in blackberry device in eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, logging

I have debuged my application of blackberry Bold 9700, and I want to see Logs which, similarly as System.out.println, or NSLog in iPhone programming,
Can anyone describe in step by step, 
I am an iPhone Developer, so having a bit issue in such basic thing, pelase help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect the Simulator to the Eclipse Console.

try 
Project>Debug As>BlackBerry Simulator

Have a look at [Blackberry Support Forum Post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/System-out-println-Eclipse-Simulator/td-p/20753)

Answer (score 0):

Yep this still stumped me even after reading @adli good answer.

The little trick is to **DEBUG** the program and **NOT** to run your program.

Note the console output becomes extremely verbose.

Also you can switch to the still switch to the the "Java Perspective" if you prefer.